# Creating a cipher, but returning error

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I am trying to make a cipher, in which you type a word, and it gets shifted by whatever the user chooses, but I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
>       at cipher.mycipher.main(mycipher.java:24)

I am not sure why I am getting this error?

Here is my code:

```
public class mycipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] storagelocation = new int[25];
        char[] letter1 = new char[25];
        char[] init = new char[25];
        Scanner consolereader = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
            'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        System.out.println("what word would you like to cipher?");
        String original = consolereader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("how much would you like to shift it by");
        int shift = consolereader.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            storagelocation[i] = i;
            letter1[i] = letters[i];
            if (letter1[i] == (original.charAt(i))) {
                letter1[i] = init[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(init));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're not giving it a 25 character input. The error message is clear and debugger will explain more

Comment: Debugger isn't helping.  Changed all of number 25 to 26, getting this error                                                                                                                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at cipher.mycipher.main(mycipher.java:24)

Comment: You know, that your code doesn't bother about the length of your input right? It will just fail, if it isn't at least 25 (or 26) characters long.

Comment: @JoshInttap `String original = consolereader.nextLine();` -- here is reduced length, not in arrays. If you enter 4-char input, so you should iterate from 0 to 3, not 24.

Comment: @xoce Please resist from highlighting normal test in ones post. It has absolutely no value in editing *"Here is my code:"* into bold text.

Comment: @Tom, tnxs, but if you check properly, you can find more than that...

Comment: @Xoce I know, but I'm not talking about that. The other stuff you did was correct and worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add condition like

```
 for (int i= 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
            storagelocation[i] = i;
            letter1[i] = letters[i];
            if (letter1[i] == original.charAt(i)) {
                letter1[i] = init[i];
            }
 }
```

Do not excede lenght of the original else the for loop will iterate until 25.

Answer (score 0):

The iteration performed should be done based on the length of the original not 25.

Your logic inside the loop looks confusing. If you explain it clearly, I can try to give you working code.